# Page crashing (possibly due to multidimensional arrays?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, crash, infinite-loop

There's a super weird bug in my programming that I just cannot figure out. Here's a fiddle of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/JocaPinto/tb07smte/4/
My problem is that if you click that button enough times, the page will crash, at least in my computer. This happened when I started using multidimensional arrays, but I tried just using one-dimensional and it still did the same. Why is it crashing? Is there any infinite loop that I'm overseeing?

Thanks to whoever answers!!

Also, for some reason Stack Overflow says I need to post code besides the link so here it is:

```js
var tasks = [
["First Task...",2],
["Second Task...",4],
["Third Task!",6]];

function nextTask() {
 var previousText = $("#taskText").text();
 var randTaskNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * tasks.length);
 do {
  $("#taskText").text(tasks[randTaskNum][0] + tasks[randTaskNum][1]);
 } while(previousText == $("#taskText").text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick='nextTask()'>Click me</button>
<p id='taskText'>Task goes here</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happen when you random the same number twice. Since your random number is generated outside the loop, `previousText == $("#taskText").text()` will always evaluate to true since you never change the number. The quick fix would be to move the random in the loop:

```
var tasks = [
["First Task...",2],
["Second Task...",4],
["Third Task!",6]];

function nextTask() {
    var previousText = $("#taskText").text();
    do {
        var randTaskNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * tasks.length);
        $("#taskText").text(tasks[randTaskNum][0] + tasks[randTaskNum][1]);
    } while(previousText == $("#taskText").text());
}
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tb07smte/5/

A better fix would be to prevent the random number to be equal to the last one.

Answer (score 2):

If you ever get a task that fails your "while" check, it will never NOT fail. You are not generating the randTaskNum INSIDE the do...while loop, so it will never change. Your loop just runs forever. Move the randTaskNum assignment to INSIDE the do...while loop.

Answer (score 2):

It will hit an infinite loop, if previousTask ends up being the same as the random task that you are choosing in the function. To solve this, assign the previous task after choosing the next random task.

```
var tasks = [
["First Task...",2],
["Second Task...",4],
["Third Task!",6]];

function nextTask() {
   var randTaskNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * tasks.length);
     do {
        $("#taskText").text(tasks[randTaskNum][0] + tasks[randTaskNum][1]);
    } while(previousText == $("#taskText").text());
        var previousText = $("#taskText").text();

}
```